# Camera 2 API throws Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
package com.example.camerastatuscheck;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    public static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.example.usbtestapp.USB_PERMISSION";
    static final int intentFlags = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S ? PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE : 0;
    static final int MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 100;
    private Context ContextofMainAcitivity;
    public IntentFilter USBconnectdisconnect_intentFilter;
    public Intent GetEXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTEDIntent;
    public PendingIntent current_usbpermissionIntent;
    public UsbDevice current_usbdevice;
    public UsbManager current_usbManager;
    private static final String TAG = "usbtestapp";
    TextureView new_textureview;
    Button new_open_camera,nextactivity;
    UsbDeviceConnection usbConnection;
    PendingIntent permissionIntent;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        camera_start();
    }
    private void camera_start() {
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(fornewpos.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }
        Log.d("camera start", "success");
        UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
        while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
            UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
            manager.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent);;
            //your code
        }
        Log.d("Camrea srtart","camera start");
        CameraManager manager =
                (CameraManager)getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics chars
                        = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
                // Do something with the characteristics
                int deviceLevel = chars.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL);
                Log.d(TAG, " **** device ["+cameraId+"] level:"+deviceLevel);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cameraId", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch(CameraAccessException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // close the app
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry!!!, you can't use this app without granting permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
private final BroadcastReceiver usbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice)intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                        if(device != null){
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Permission granded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
public boolean supportsExternalCameras() {
        return this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_EXTERNAL);
    }
}
```

### Log

> 2023-01-07 15:31:55.318 23651-23651 libc                    com.example.cmaera5                  E  Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"

### AndroidManifest

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

### Description

I have been using the above code to capture an image from an External USB Camera (Web Cam). This code is working perfectly on most devices, but on some device, it throws

> 2023-01-07 15:31:55.318 23651-23651 libc   com.example.cmaera5  E
> Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"

In some devices it shows the above error message in logcat while trying to get the camera ID to open the camera

I gave permission to camera, external storage and USB device

### The device Configuration that shows the error

1. Android OS version: 9.0
2. API Level         : 28

Please provide me with an explanation of what is happening.